# Yii2 Display Related Data not in Array, not using Listview or Gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a main view called Dashboard.php in which I want to display a logged in employee's cell phone (from the employee_phone table which stores all employee phone numbers and are differentiated by 'phone_type' (ie cell, home, main)) in an arbitrary field labeled as 'phone 1:' on the view, then display either their 'home' or 'main' number as 'phone 2:'.  Please note, for clarity I left out the 'home' phone provider as I'm sure I can figure it out if someone can help with the 'cell' phone type.  I cannot get any phone number to display and I've tried several configurations.  Any help is appreciated and I apologize in advance for my newness.  I've read this page: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data and it seems like it fits my criteria but I just can't make it work.  I've also read the related questions here on SO but they seem related to working with data in an array and displaying it in a ListView or Gridview.  I also don't seem to be able to get the provider to be able to access the method getEmployeeCellPhone() with the magic method of employeeCellPhone.

I have two tables:

employee Table:
id 
user_id

employee_phone Table:
id
employee_id 
phone_number 
phone_type

Employee.php Model:

```
public function getEmployeePhones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\frontend\models\EmployeePhone::className(), ['employee_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getEmployeeCellPhone()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\frontend\models\EmployeePhone::className(), ['employee_id' => 'id'])
        ->where(['=', 'phone_type', 'Cell'])
        ->all();
}
```

EmployeeController:

```
public function actionDashboard($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $providerCellPhone = $model->employeeCellPhone;
    return $this->render('dashboard', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'providerCellPhone' => $providerCellPhone,
    ]);
}
```

Dashboard.php View:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
            Phone 1: <?= $model->$providerCellPhone ?><br>
            Phone 2: <?= $model->$providerHomePhone ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following to check if your issue is solved -

```
//EmployeeController
public function actionDashboard($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return $this->render('dashboard', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

And the view file -

```
//Dashboard.php View
<div class="col-lg-3">
    Phone 1: <?= $model->employeeCellPhone[0]->phone_number  ?><br>
    Phone 2: <?= $model->employeeHomePhone[0]->phone_number  ?>
</div>
```

To properly output the value `$model->employeeCellPhone[0]` is required because in your `getEmployeeCellPhone()` function, you have used the `->all()` function. The Dashboard code is written assuming that in DB only one phone number will exist per user per phone_type. If that is not the case, you need to loop over `$model->employeeCellPhone` in the view and get the desired output.

Also, your Model code pasted above, doesn't show the `getEmployeeHomePhone()` function, I am assuming you have it there.

Comment: Correct. But as mentioned in my answer you can simply do a `foreach` loop and print the output

Comment: Bad mistake - I will update the answer. I just printed `employeeCellPhone[0]` which is the object. We need to print `employeeCellPhone[0]->phone_number`. This should get rid of the error

Comment: I get the error, 'Object of class frontend\models\EmployeePhone could not be converted to string' when I do it that way.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again for helping, but isn't there a way without looping to simply pick the phone numbers of the logged in user with the phone_type of 'cell'?

Comment: I converted getEmployeeCellPhone() into hasMany but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Looping is probably the best way with your current code setup. Else you can modify `getEmployeeCellPhone()` to return not `EmployeePhone` object but only the `phone_number` field as an array. And then in your view file simply do an `implode()` on that array with a delimiter of your choice. But this implementation also depends on how you want your UI to look.

Comment: Using employeeCellPhone[0]->phone_number works like a charm.  Thanks!  Sorry for the confusion.  Sometimes the comments don't update fast enough. :)

Comment: Great that it works for you. If your issue is solved, request you to please upvote & accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer but I don't have enough rep to upvote it.  I'm sorry.  I would love to give you ten upvotes if I could.  Thanks again.  Happy Holidays.

Comment: @Marko not a problem. I hadn't noticed your reps etc., so my bad. I am glad to have provided some help. Season's Greetings.